# Identify a class in an array of different classes not using instanceOf

Tags: java, android, instanceof

I don't want to hardwire the class name and use the `instanceOf` but dynamically identifying the class

Lets say I have

```
// add fragments
mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, class1.class.getName()));
mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, class2.class.getName()));

public class class1 extends SherlockListFragment{
   public static final String TAG = "class1";
}
```

All classes have the `extends` SherlockActivity or SherlockListFragment so they have a common base class `Fragment`. How can I now when iterating trough the array get e.g. the `static` tag or something else that will identify the `Class` without using `instanceOf`. I have some ides but wanted to get some input so I can learn

```
 public static final String TAG = "class1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method in the base class which returns the tag.  Then iterate over your structure and get the tag for each subtype.

```
public class SherlockListFragment{
    public String getTag(){ 
        return TAG;
    }
}
```

You don't need to determine the exact subtype of class. Any time you start encountering odd problems like this, I'd suggest reworking design first rather than finding a work around.

Comment: Yea this is odd I kind of agree but wanted to learn some technik.
Your answer will do it since the Sherlock library is opensource.

Comment: Great! Please remember to accept an answer to close this question.

Comment: Was looking for something using reflection,,clazz = x.getClass() clazz.getField("fieldName"); (and the pros and cons about that). yea it's ugly I know

Comment: You can manage it certainly, but I do not recommend it. Accessing a field via reflection is much slower than not using reflection. Really- just rework your design. If you insist, I'll help with a reflection solution, but its gonna be ugly, confusing, and slow. The correct approach here is to use inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a method in your `Fragment` class as below:

```
public class Fragment {
    ...
    public String getTag() {
       return this.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    }
}

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
   ...
}

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
   ...
}
```

Now, I tested it using simple code below:

```
Fragment f = new Fragment1();
Fragment f1 = new Fragment2();

System.out.println(f.getTag());
System.out.println(f1.getTag());
```

Which gives output:

```
Fragment1
Fragment2
```

Comment: You're right but the Fragment is android.support.v4.app.Fragment and that's not an option for me

Comment: @Erik You can just call `f.getClass().getCanonicalName()` but it will not be too much different from `instanceof`. I doubt there would be any elegant solution if you can not change `Fragment` class.